# build failure with quarkus

Tags: java, aws-lambda, quarkus

I have some AWS lambda functions in my project and I´m trying to build it using Quarkus, to improve lambda performance.
When I try to build it using:

```
mvn clean package -Pnative -Dnative-image.docker-build=true
```

I get the following stack:

```
Error: Unsupported features in 2 methods
Detailed message:
Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.getOutputContext(). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.

Trace: 
    at parsing com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.close(CBORGenerator.java:903)

Call path from entry point to com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.close(): 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.close(CBORGenerator.java:900)
    at java.io.FileDescriptor.closeAll(FileDescriptor.java:345)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:396)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3639)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.flush(DeflaterOutputStream.java:277)
    at java.io.PrintStream.flush(PrintStream.java:417)
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.functions.JNIFunctions.ExceptionDescribe(JNIFunctions.java:772)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.JNIFunctions_ExceptionDescribe_b5412f7570bccae90b000bc37855f00408b2ad73(generated:0)

Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: org.joda.time.Interval.parseWithOffset(java.lang.String). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.

Trace: 
    at parsing com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.IntervalDeserializer.deserialize(IntervalDeserializer.java:62)

Call path from entry point to com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.IntervalDeserializer.deserialize(JsonParser, DeserializationContext): 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.IntervalDeserializer.deserialize(IntervalDeserializer.java:37)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.IntervalDeserializer.deserialize(IntervalDeserializer.java:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1228)
    at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AbstractLambdaPollLoop$1.run(AbstractLambdaPollLoop.java:78)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:517)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:192)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.PosixJavaThreads_pthreadStartRoutine_e1f4a8c0039f8337338252cd8734f63a79b5e3df(generated:0)

com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Unsupported features in 2 methods
Detailed message:
Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.getOutputContext(). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.

Trace: 
    at parsing com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.close(CBORGenerator.java:903)

Call path from entry point to com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.close(): 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.close(CBORGenerator.java:900)
    at java.io.FileDescriptor.closeAll(FileDescriptor.java:345)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:396)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3639)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.flush(DeflaterOutputStream.java:277)
    at java.io.PrintStream.flush(PrintStream.java:417)
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.functions.JNIFunctions.ExceptionDescribe(JNIFunctions.java:772)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.JNIFunctions_ExceptionDescribe_b5412f7570bccae90b000bc37855f00408b2ad73(generated:0)

Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: org.joda.time.Interval.parseWithOffset(java.lang.String). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.

Trace: 

    at parsing com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.IntervalDeserializer.deserialize(IntervalDeserializer.java:62)

Call path from entry point to com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.IntervalDeserializer.deserialize(JsonParser, DeserializationContext): 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.IntervalDeserializer.deserialize(IntervalDeserializer.java:37)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.IntervalDeserializer.deserialize(IntervalDeserializer.java:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1228)
    at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AbstractLambdaPollLoop$1.run(AbstractLambdaPollLoop.java:78)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:517)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:192)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.PosixJavaThreads_pthreadStartRoutine_e1f4a8c0039f8337338252cd8734f63a79b5e3df(generated:0)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:79)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FallbackFeature.reportAsFallback(FallbackFeature.java:217)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:765)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:555)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:468)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)

Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: Unsupported features in 2 methods
Detailed message:
Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.getOutputContext(). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.

Trace: 

    at parsing com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.close(CBORGenerator.java:903)
Call path from entry point to com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.close(): 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.close(CBORGenerator.java:900)
    at java.io.FileDescriptor.closeAll(FileDescriptor.java:345)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:396)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3639)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.flush(DeflaterOutputStream.java:277)
    at java.io.PrintStream.flush(PrintStream.java:417)
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.functions.JNIFunctions.ExceptionDescribe(JNIFunctions.java:772)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.JNIFunctions_ExceptionDescribe_b5412f7570bccae90b000bc37855f00408b2ad73(generated:0)

Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: org.joda.time.Interval.parseWithOffset(java.lang.String). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.

Trace: 
    at parsing com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.IntervalDeserializer.deserialize(IntervalDeserializer.java:62)

Call path from entry point to com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.IntervalDeserializer.deserialize(JsonParser, DeserializationContext): 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.IntervalDeserializer.deserialize(IntervalDeserializer.java:37)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.IntervalDeserializer.deserialize(IntervalDeserializer.java:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1228)
    at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AbstractLambdaPollLoop$1.run(AbstractLambdaPollLoop.java:78)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:517)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:192)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.PosixJavaThreads_pthreadStartRoutine_e1f4a8c0039f8337338252cd8734f63a79b5e3df(generated:0)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatures.report(UnsupportedFeatures.java:129)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:762)
    ... 8 more

Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

I have no idea what could be, because I don´t use the methods listed in stacktrace.

Anyone already used quarkus to build AWS-lambda projects?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -3):

I don't know this specific problem, but i had problems with quarkus before with native image. You could try building with te JVM, graalvm it's not very reliable yet.

Comment: but isn´t the native image with graalvm the main reason to use quarkus? in my case, to avoid cold starts in lambdas.

Comment: yes, but in certain cases, there's nothing you can do about it. Graalvm has its limitations

Comment: ok..so how did you build it without graalvm? I don´t have it installed here and I´m using Win10

Comment: If you want to compile your code into a GraalVM native image, you have to stick to some rules. For example, most of the dynamic stuff like class loading during runtime or reflection is not or only partially supported. Without having looked at it, I assume that the Jackson CBOR library does something which is not supported by the GraalVM native compiler. So, this is not about stability of GraalVM. It’s about how suited your code or the libs you use are for native image compilation.

Comment: There is a bug in Quarkus right now, this shouldn't suppose to happen, at least not to a cleanly generated project etc. I had the same issue and created this ticket https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/12592

Comment: did you try to add quarkus-jackson dependencies ?